# If as $x\to\infty$, $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ both are indetermained. Why does $\arctan(x)$, being $\cos(x)/\sin(x)$, approaches $\pi$/2?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I mean I can see it in the graph in geoalgebra, and I know that lim $x\to\pi/2$  of $\tan(x)$ approaches $\infty$. But this explanation still doesn't make sense to me. Is this just how it is defined? If it is, what element of the definition of arctan functions result in this behavior?

Comment: $\arctan x$ is not $\cos x/\sin x.$ That is the cotangent, $\cot x.$

Comment: You might be confused by the notion that "arc-tangent is the inverse function of tangent." This doesn't mean multiplicative inverse, this means function inverse.

Comment: $\tan^{-1}x \ne \frac{1}{\tan x}$

Comment: ohh that make sense

Comment: Incidentally, $\cot x$ can be defined as either $\frac1{\tan x}$ or $\tan(\frac\pi2-x)$. The latter is why it's called "cotangent" (compare the relationship between sine and cosine).

Comment: On the other hand, as $x\to\left(\frac\pi2\right)^\pm$, $\tan(x)\to \pm\infty$